# Batch arcpy.CopyRaster after arcpy.ASCIItoRaster

Tags: python, arcpy, batch, geotiff-tiff, esri-ascii-raster

I'm new to arcpy and am having trouble running CopyRaster. Do I need a separate for loop for this process like I have below?

```
import os,arcpy, glob  


filepath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthtest"   

outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"  


ascList = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.asc")  

print ascList  

rasterpath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"

LastOutFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowrast"

rasterList = glob.glob(rasterpath + "/*.tif")
print rasterList


for ascFile in ascList:  

    outRaster = outFolder + "/" + os.path.split(ascFile)[1][:-3] + "tif"  
    print outRaster  

    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascFile, outRaster, "FLOAT")



for rasterFile in rasterList:   

    LastOutRaster = LastOutFolder + "/" + os.path.split(rasterFile)[1][:-3] + "tif"
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout",r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowrast","DEFAULTS","","","NONE","NONE","16_BIT_UNSIGNED")
```

**Edit:**

After modifying the script, I get the following error:

> ERROR 000876: Output raster:
>   C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthtest\snowdepthN0001.asc's
>   extension is invalid for the output raster format.

```
import os,arcpy, glob

filepath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthtest"
outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"
ascList = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.asc")

rasterpath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"

OutFolderTwo = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowrast"

rasterList = glob.glob(rasterpath + "/*.asc")
print rasterList

for ascFile in ascList:
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, ascFile)
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascFile, outRaster, "FLOAT")

rasterList = glob.glob(outFolder + "/*.tif")

for rasterFile in rasterList:

    OutRasterTwo = os.path.join(OutFolderTwo, rasterFile)
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasterFile, OutRasterTwo, "DEFAULTS","","","NONE","NONE","16_BIT_UNSIGNED")
```

Comment: What error are are you receiving?

Comment: I don't get an error, but the process stops after batch ascIItoRaster, and does not execute CopyRaster. Also, I'm not sure what the lines beginning with 'outRaster' and LastOutRaster' are doing being new to arcpy.

Comment: CopyRaster syntax is : arcpy.CopyRaster_management(INPUT, OUTPUT). Don't you want to make the INPUT = LastOutRaster? Otherwise, you're just copying "snowdepthout" x times. You don't make use of LastOutRaster as it is.

Comment: @phloem I replaced the directory paths in CopyRaster_management with 'rasterpath' and 'LastOutFolder' respectively, still I cannot execute copyraster.

Comment: The answer to your main question is, no, you do not need a separate loop, in fact it would be easier to reuse the variable outRaster in your call to CopyRaster (e.g. CopyRaster(outRaster, newRaster)).

Comment: @phloem `arcpy.CopyRaster_management(outRaster,OutFolderTwo,"DEFAULTS","","","NONE","NONE","16_BIT_UNSIGNED")` I got rid of the second for loop and appended the first for loop with this code. The copyraster process now tries to execute and fails. I get Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 22, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 11034, in CopyRaster     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Raster dataset already exists Failed to execute (CopyRaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bordering on a shot-in-the-dark, but try the following changes.  Essentially, your parameters were off and you need to generate a list of TIFFs after they are created, not before.  Finally, I assume you are using Copy Raster to convert to 16 bit unsigned, otherwise, you can drop this command entirely.

```
import os,arcpy, glob

filepath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthtest"
outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"
ascList = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.asc")

rasterpath = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthout"

LastOutFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowrast"

for ascFile in ascList:
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, os.path.basename(ascFile).split(".")[0] + "tif")
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascFile, outRaster, "FLOAT")

rasterList = glob.glob(outFolder + "/*.tif")

for rasterFile in rasterList:
    LastOutRaster = os.path.join(LastOutFolder, rasterFile + "tif")
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(rasterFile, LastOutRaster, "DEFAULTS","","","NONE","NONE","16_BIT_UNSIGNED")
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, yes I need to convert to 16 bit unsigned to I can go on to create color maps. I follow your code and it seems to make sense, however, I get: ERROR 000876: Output raster: C:\VMshared\small_example_valley2\snowdepthtest\snowdepthN0001.asctif's extension is invalid for the output raster format.

Comment: I think `glob.glob()` generates the entire path and file name with the extension, so try extracting just the basename and change the extension (note. script updated to reflect this).